# Trying to make a c++ class easier to use with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying, just for learning, to make a Vector class with a derived Vector3 class. The first Vector class, has a double* v; pointer for the array and some [] operators for easier data access, and Vector3 also has x, y, z pointers.

The important parts of the classes are like:

```
class Vector{
protected:
    double* v;
    int size_;

public:
    [ ... a lot of stuff ... ]
    double & operator [](int i);
}

class Vector3 : public Vector{
public:
    double* x;      //Access to v[0]
    double* y;      //Access to v[1]
    double* z;      //Access to v[2]

    Vector3();
    Vector3(double,double,double);
};
```

So my intention is to make a code like this work:

```
//You can create a Vector3 and access with x, y, z values:
Vector3 v3 = Vector3(10,9,8);

cout << "Testing v3.x -- v3.y -- v3.z" << endl;
cout << v3.x << " -- " << v3.y << " -- " << v3.z << endl;

//And also change its values
v3.x = 5;
v3.y = 1;
v3.z = 6;

//Now, the two following couts should print the same:
cout << "Testing v3.x -- v3.y -- v3.z and v3[0] -- v3[1] -- v3[2]" << endl;
cout << v3.x << " -- " << v3.y << " -- " << v3.z << endl;
cout << v3[0]<< " -- " << v3[1]<< " -- " << v3[2]<< endl;
```

And my question is:

Is it possible to do this **without modifying that last code**?

I know I can easily make this work changing the v3.x for v3.x[0] or something like that but I want it to be more intuitive.

Comment: Take a look at how GLM library does it. TL;DR it uses unions with **a lot** of compatibility checks. Your approach requires a lot of redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need `operator=` for `Vector3` class, you could change pointers to references.

```
class Vector3 : public Vector{
public:
    double& x;      //Access to v[0]
    double& y;      //Access to v[1]
    double& z;      //Access to v[2]

    Vector3();
    Vector3(double,double,double);
};
```